# How to Remove Apps & Tasks from My Profile In Sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, master-page

How to remove Apps & Tasks from My Profile In SharePoint 2013 which is on left hand navigation shown in the image. also I want to add search center Enterprise page link in the same left hand navigation. How do I achieve it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your only way to remove these links is via JavaScript or CSS.

The Quicklaunch for the MySite is generated by a custom SiteMap provider `MySiteHostQuickLaunchProvider` that generates said links. You could also create your own provider but that I guess that would be a bit over the top if all you want to do is hide those links.

I don't know why Microsoft chose to implement it this way because they could have just filled the `SPWeb.Navigation` Quicklaunch links... oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Apps and Tasks are part of the out of the box functionality. Even if you remove the links the destination pages will still exits.

Are you planning on using the Task Management Service Application? If so, you will need the Task page.

Users with a Personal Site can create Lists and Libraries to store their content. That is what the Apps link is for. Hiding the link will not prevent them from creating new content (or managing their content) it will just make it harder to get to.

OK, now that I have said all that. You can go and open the My Site Host (as an administrator) and edit the links on the left navy and remove the link to Tasks. (It looks like Apps will be a bit more challenging.)